# How to Categorically Relocate Records Using Grep

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I need to parse a file containing records beginning with a keyword and
selectively write those records to separate category files. After this
is done, the records that were extracted need to be removed from the main
file. Using bash, is grepping the best way?

The following function and loop does the extraction part:

```
declare -a keywords
declare -f extract_records

keywords=(alpha bravo gamma delta)

extract_records() {
    grep -E "^($1 )" main_file >> category_file.$1
}

for i in "${keywords[@]}"; do
    extract_records "$i"
done
```

Then to re-compress the main file:

```
grep -E -v \
  -e "^alpha " \
  -e "^bravo " \
  -e "^gamma " \
  -e "^delta " \
main_file >> main_file.$$
```

The `main_file.$$` is optionally sorted, replacing the original.
Here, the keyword list is specified twice. It would be better to use the array again for the re-compress part so that only one
keyword list is needed, something like:

```
grep -E -v "^(${keywords[@]})" main_file >> main_file.$$
```

but this does not work as each keyword needs a pattern specifier.
Is there a simpler way? Can each record be removed as it's being
extracted, rather than this two-part approach? The keyword list can
be hundreds, loaded from a file, and read into the array (not shown
here). Managing two sets of keywords is prone to a mismatch and loss
of data. Outside of bash, is there a Python or other solution?

EDIT: Mon Feb 20 22:52:53 EST 2023

A minimal representative example follows...

The original `main_file` consists of 10 data records:

```
alpha 1
bravo 1
gamma 1
delta 1
omicron 1
sigma 1
alpha 2
bravo 2
gamma 2
delta 2
```

The category files created by extraction...
`main_file.alpha`

```
alpha 1
alpha 2
```

`main_file.bravo`

```
bravo 1
bravo 2
```

`main_file.gamma`

```
gamma 1
gamma 2
```

`main_file.delta`

```
delta 1
delta 2
```

The resultant compressed `main_file` is to hold what was not extracted:

```
omicron 1
sigma 1
```

On steeldriver's suggestion, creation of an `exclusion_args` array from
the `keywords` array does compile the correct patterns for what could be
an inversion grep and does SOLVE my "two independent lists" problem:

```
declare -a exclusion_args
for k in "${keywords[@]}"; do exclusion_args+=( -e "\"^$k \"" ); done
printf "%s " "${exclusion_args[@]}"
```

`-e "^alpha " -e "^bravo " -e "^gamma " -e "^delta "`

The above string reproduces what was first posted with the "grep -E -v" as
far as the inversion patterns.  Correct, the grouping parens were not needed.
Now in what way can the above string be used as additional arguments to the
following grep mock-up:

`grep -E -v $(printf " %s " "${exclusion_args[@]}") main_file`

If correct, this should yield only the `omicron` and `sigma` records.

An `echo` of the above `printf` unexpectedly removes the leading `-e` seen here:

`"^alpha " -e "^bravo " -e "^gamma " -e "^delta "`

and of course this disrupts the inversion pattern for grep. Perhaps this is why the inversion grep returns all 10 records and excludes none.

And there might be a better way to take the input to the output than this design.

Comment: While you *could* construct an array of grep arguments from the array of keywords as `args=( -v -w ); for k in "${keywords[@]}"; do args+=( -e "^$k" ); done` for example (I don't see the need for `-E` or the grouping parentheses, and `-w` is probably more robust than adding an explicit trailing space character) likely there is a better way to achieve what you want - it's hard to propose a solution without a minimal representative example of your input and desired output(s).

Comment: Added the info you asked for. See question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could construct an array of grep arguments from the array of keywords, like

```
args=( -v -w )
for k in "${keywords[@]}"; do 
  args+=( -e "^$k" )
done
```

for example (I don't see the need for -E or the grouping parentheses, and -w is probably more robust than adding an explicit trailing space character), it would be more natural IMHO to use a more fully featured text processing language. For example in GNU awk, you could read the keywords into an internal array and then process the whole `main_file` in a single pass:

```
keywords=(alpha bravo gamma delta)

printf '%s\n' "${keywords[@]}" | gawk -i inplace '
  BEGIN{inplace::enable=0} 
  NR==FNR {keywords[$0]; next} 
  ($1 in keywords) {print > (FILENAME "." $1); next} 
  {print}
' - inplace::enable=1 main_file
```

resulting in

```
$ head main_file*
==> main_file <==
omicron 1
sigma 1

==> main_file.alpha <==
alpha 1
alpha 2

==> main_file.bravo <==
bravo 1
bravo 2

==> main_file.delta <==
delta 1
delta 2

==> main_file.gamma <==
gamma 1
gamma 2
```

(switching `inplace::enable` on and off is not strictly necessary - it just suppresses a warning about `in-place editing for invalid FILENAME  '-'`).

---

If you are determined to use a shell loop instead, then `sed` is a more appropriate regex tool than `grep` - which is intended for searching only rather than searching and replacing. So for example

```
for k in "${keywords[@]}"; do 
  sed -i -e "/^$k/{w main_file.$k" -e "d}" main_file
done
```

however I'd suggest that even with `sed`, a better approach would be to turn the keyword array into a sed script and then execute that as a single instruction:

```
printf '%s\n' "${keywords[@]}" | sed 's:.*:/&/{w main_file.&\nd}:' | 
  sed -i.bak -f - main_file
```

In fact, I'd choose the latter over the gawk solution if you don't mind hard-coding the basename `main_file`.

Comment: steeldriver This is excellent and the sed solution more efficient I'm sure. Thank you for this alternate approach.

Comment: @Paul_Capo you're welcome - please be aware that the sed approach may need tweaking if any of your actual keywords contain regex metacharacters. See for example [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac)